# Was not able to run nightwatch.js tests with mocha "Ensure the done() callback is being called"

Tags: automated-tests, mocha.js, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

Nearly every single example i've found on web isn't well explained how mocha should be implemented and used with nightwatchJS.

Whatever i do i am not able to avoid that error message, even if i follow all steps from [official nightwatch how-to use mocha](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-mocha)
Only thing that i was able to do is to at least make google chrome browser open and thats it.

Here is the code i am trying to run

```js
var nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

describe('Google', function() {

    var client = nightwatch.initClient({
        // Pass here options from nightwatch.json

        // selenium logs; change it to true if you want to see them in console
        silent : false,

        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: "chrome",
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            acceptSslCerts: true
        }
    });

    var browser = client.api();

    // Mocha timeout
    this.timeout(15000);

    it('Demo test Google', function (done) {
        browser
            .url('http://www.google.com')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
            .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
            .click('button[name=btnG]')
            .pause(1000)
            .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
            .end();


        client.start(done);
    });
});
```

And this is the error message that always happen to me after the browser pop up:

```html
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session 
 - data:  {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","javascriptEnabled":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"platform":"ANY"}} 
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":113}
    1) Demo test Google


  0 passing (15s)
  1 failing

  1) Google Demo test Google:
     Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question states that there is no great documentation regarding how to set up nightwatch with mocha. I discovered this to be the case myself this weekend as I looked to set up my nightwatch tests with mocha. 
I was able to set up my nightwatch tests without seeing the done callback error by doing the following:

I used a **nightwatch.conf.js** but I believe you can also do the following in **nightwatch.json**:

```
module.exports = {
  src_folders : ["test"],
  test_runner: {
    type: 'mocha',
    options: {
      ui: 'bdd',
      reporter: 'spec'
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Simple right? 
**This allows mocha to run your nightwatch tests**.
Much simpler, friendlier syntax IMO.

**Here are the relevant parts of my package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "nightwatch-mocha",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "nightwatch": "nightwatch -c ./nightwatch.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^73.0.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "nightwatch": "^1.0.19"
  }
}
```

I've installed **chromedriver** so I can run tests via **chrome**.

**Mocha and Nightwatch** are also installed.

I've created a script called **nightwatch** inside the **scripts** object.

This will run nightwatch with mocha when I run `npm run nightwatch` from the command line when I'm located in the root of the project.

In addition, using the nightwatch.json or nightwatch.conf.js keeps that configuration out of your tests - you don't want to have to initialize that whenever you are writing a new test suite when you can do it once and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the `done()` callback in the end of the chain instead. I'm not fully up to speed with `client.start()`, but I'm quite sure you want to signal the test is done when the chain has reached its end.

```js
var nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

describe('Google', function() {

    var client = nightwatch.initClient({
        // Pass here options from nightwatch.json

        // selenium logs; change it to true if you want to see them in console
        silent : false,

        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: "chrome",
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            acceptSslCerts: true
        }
    });

    var browser = client.api();

    // Mocha timeout
    this.timeout(15000);

    it('Demo test Google', function (done) {
        browser
            .url('http://www.google.com')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
            .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
            .click('button[name=btnG]')
            .pause(1000)
            .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
            .end(done);


        client.start();
    });
});
```